# SSRS set default parameter for subscription only

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible in SSRS to set a default parameter value for a report subscription only, but not set a default when the report is run manually?

I have the default dates I want to use for the subscription generated in a dataset, but I'd like to **only** use default dates for the subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using data-driven subscription and creating a query inside the subscription to generate default parameters

Comment: I was about to suggest a Boolean USE_DEFAULT parameter that defaults to FALSE. Then make the default values for your other parameters `=IIF(Parameters!USE_DEFAULT.Value, TODAY.AddDays(1 - TODAY.DayOfYear), NOTHING)` Your subscription would set the USE_DEFAULT to TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea.

1. Select the target report and click manage.
2. Select Create Linked Report and Rename it to denote Subscription
3. Set the desired parameters for subscriptions on the new linked report.

   NOTE : Parameters can be set independently for linked reports.
4. Point your subscriptions to the linked report.

   NOTE : If you modify the original report the changes will show up in all linked reports as well.